# Session Timeout Issue in SQLServer mode

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sitecore, session-timeout, sitecore7.2

I am facing strange Session Timeout issue.
The mode I am using in SQLServer, and set the timeout value to 20 minutes (Both Session and cookie time out value), but my session expires within 2 minute.
When I check the session value in SQL Server `ASPStateTempSessions` Table in `ASPState`,
the Timeout value is set to 1 minute.
Where this value is setting other than web.config? I verified `machin.config` also, didn't find any timeout value there.

Config Value:

```
sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="SQLServer" sqlCommandTimeout="600" 
sqlConnectionString="server=servername;user id=abcd;password=****" timeout="10"
```

This works fine in my test environment, but same config is not working in other server (staging), here timeout value set to 1.

Please let me know if you have any inputs.
Thanks in advance.

-Sharath

Comment: Are the versions the same both on your development server, and the production server?

Comment: yes, versions are same

Comment: Did you try adding allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" to the sessionState element?

Answer (score 0):

add web.config file this code

```
<sessionstate timeout="15"></sessionstate>
```

add perticular page this code

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Demo/Demo.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Timeout value already set in the config under sessionState value, but whatever the value I set, session will expire before 2 min and value in DB(Timeout) set to 1 min. Also, we don't have any authentication here, so i think it is not required any update in the authetication mode